# Is it possible to use Filezilla server as an alternate to Apache Web Server ?

Tags: apache, webserver

Can i use Filezilla Server as an alternate to Apache Web Server. After that can i run PHP or .Net or JSP server side files, by placing the scripts there ?

If not, why can be the practical use of Filezilla server to install on the local machine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can i use Filezilla Server as an alternate to Apache Web Server.

Filezilla is an FTP server. Apache HTTPD is an HTTP server. They aren't drop in replacements for each other.

> After that can i run PHP or .Net or JSP server side files, by placing the scripts there ?

No

> If not, why can be the practical use of Filezilla server to install on the local machine ?

To run an FTP service.

Comment: Why would i need an FTP service on my local machine ? ( It's understandable to be used, if my machine is a server though)

Comment: To let people connect to it remotely and upload files. I've no idea if you would find that useful, and if you don't then don't install an FTP server.